# File wont open using fopen

Tags: c, csv, fopen

I cannot seem to open this .txt file,it also doesnt work with .csv files
How do i get it to open?
(this is a program im trying to make that searches for a phrase inside a csv file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_WIDTH 320

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char bigString[200];
    FILE* csv;
    csv = fopen("C:\Users\Ofek\Desktop\Folder\source.txt","r+t");
    while (feof(csv) != 1)
    {
        if (fgetc(csv) != '\n')
        {
            char bigString[i] = fgetc(csv);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Is there any more detail you can give about what is going wrong when you try to open the file?

Answer (score 1):

Replace all single backslashes with two backslashes:

```
C:\\Users\\Ofek\\Desktop\\Folder\\source.txt
```

Otherwise the character after the backslash will be interpreted as control characters.

Comment: Or, use `/`, which is perfectly valid on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

there are several problems with the posted code. Here are a few:

```
1) do not use 'feof()' for a loop control, it will not work as expected. 
2) when setting the bigString[i] variable, a second call to fgetc() is used. That results in the first, 3, 5, 7, etc characters being lost.
Suggest: save the results of the call to fgetc() in the 'if' statement and use that saved value.
```

the following code corrects 'most' of the problems in the posted code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{

    int i = 0;
    int inputChar;
    char bigString[200] = {'\0'};

    FILE* csv;
    if( NULL == (csv = fopen("C:\\Users\\Ofek\\Desktop\\Folder\\source.txt","r+t") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for source.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while (EOF != ( inputChar = fgetc(csv) ) )
    {
        if ('\n' != inputChar)
        {
            bigString[i] = inputChar;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf( "Input file, without newlines: %s\n", bigString );
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```